# Error retrieving sharepoint folders with Office365-REST-Python-Client

Tags: python, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, office365api

I'm working on a python project which contains a function that is supposed to retrieve a folder from the sharepoint of the company using the [Office365-REST-Python-Client libary](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/tree/62ba801e7f3600a43af09b32b0f5635737449bc8).

I already created an app and registered it to the sharepoint like in the [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs)
But tbh the Microsoft documentation is quite hard to follow and leaves questions open. (Atleast for beginners)

What I have so far:

```
import json
import os
import sys
import traceback
from office365.runtime.auth.client_credential import ClientCredential
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext




site_url ="https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/Colaboration"
client_id = "XXXX"
client_secret = "XXXX"


def connectAuth():
    # Initialize the client credentials
    client_credentials = ClientCredential(client_id, client_secret)

    # create client context object
    ctx = ClientContext('https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com').with_credentials(client_credentials)
    print(ctx)

    try:
        folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_guest_url('/sites/Colaboration')
        
        ctx.load(folder)
        ctx.execute_query()
        files = folder.files
        ctx.load(files)
        ctx.execute_query()

    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
        print('Problem printing out library contents')   
        #sys.exit(1)


connectAuth()
```

Error displayed in VSCode:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\LangChain\sharepoint.py", line 51, in connectAuth
    ctx.execute_query()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\client_runtime_context.py", line 181, in execute_query      
    self.pending_request().execute_query(qry)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\client_request.py", line 62, in execute_query
    raise ClientRequestException(*e.args, response=e.response)
office365.runtime.client_request_exception.ClientRequestException: ('-1, System.UriFormatException', 'Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.', '500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/GetFolderByGuestUrl')
```

I also couldnt find out what the App Domain & App Redirect URI is supposed to be. After 2 days of trying different solutions found on the internet I'm on my wits end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have below **folders** in my SharePoint document library like this:

[image]

When I ran your code in my environment to fetch folders, I got **same error** as below:

```py
import json
import os
import sys
import traceback
from office365.runtime.auth.client_credential import ClientCredential
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

site_url ="https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/Collaboration"
client_id = "XXXX"
client_secret = "XXXX"

def connectAuth():
    # Initialize the client credentials
    client_credentials = ClientCredential(client_id, client_secret)

    # create client context object
    ctx = ClientContext('https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com').with_credentials(client_credentials)
    print(ctx)

    try:
        folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_guest_url('/sites/Collaboration')
        
        ctx.load(folder)
        ctx.execute_query()
        files = folder.files
        ctx.load(files)
        ctx.execute_query()
        
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
        print('Problem printing out library contents')   
        #sys.exit(1)
        
connectAuth()
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, I modified the code by changing to different method and got **folders name** successfully in response like this:

```py
import json
import os
import sys
import traceback
from office365.runtime.auth.client_credential import ClientCredential
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

site_url = "https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/Collaboration"
client_id = "xxxxxx"
client_secret = "xxxxx"

relative_url = "/sites/Collaboration/<doclibname>"

def connectAuth():
    # Initialize the client credentials
    client_credentials = ClientCredential(client_id, client_secret)

    # create client context object
    ctx = ClientContext(site_url).with_credentials(client_credentials)
    print(ctx)

    try:
        libraryRoot = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_path(relative_url)
        
        ctx.load(libraryRoot)
        ctx.execute_query()

        folder = libraryRoot.folders
        ctx.load(folder)
        ctx.execute_query()

        print("Number of folders:", len(folder))
        print("Folder names:")
        for folder_item in folder:
            ctx.load(folder_item)
            ctx.execute_query()
            print(folder_item.properties["Name"])

    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
        print('Problem printing out library contents')   
        #sys.exit(1)

connectAuth()
```

**Response:**

[image]